# Probability: General form $\sum \binom{n}{k} x^k (1-x)^{n-k}$

Tags: probability, summation, combinations

To calculate the probability of 'at least' in Binomial distributions, you have to find the sum which I'm trying to find a simplified form of 
$$
\sum_{i=k}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k (1-x)^{n-k},
$$
where $x \in [0,1]$ and $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Maybe this has been done. I have had no luck and I don't know the terminology to request for it directly.

Comment: What does the question have to do with the title?

Comment: I started off with an unfair coin say 70% heads, 30% tails. (won't let me start a be line without submitting). so I wanted to find out the probability of getting at least 2 tails in 5 tosses, so I determine that I should find the probability of getting 5 heads, then the probability of 4 heads and subtract from 1. And I end up with: 1 - (0.7^5 + 0.7^4)

Comment: @Aeru You seemed to have an incorrect summation for what you seem to want to calculate. I have edited the question to, hopefully, correct the error, make the title match the question, and make it clearer what you are asking for and why. Feel free to roll back the edit if I have gone too far.

Comment: Yes ${n\choose k}$ means the same as $_nC_k$.

Comment: thanks everyone, I couldn't vote up, but I'd vote for all of ya.

Comment: In general there’s no nice form for partial sums of expressions involving binomial coefficients. However, there is an expression for the c.d.f. of the binomial distribution in terms of an integral that might be of interest to you: see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you mean $x^i(1-x)^{n-i}$ inside the sum.  In that case, I think there is no nicer formula, except in special cases, such as $k=0$ or $k=n$ or $x=1/2$.

Maple evaluates this in terms of a hypergeometric; but it is really just the definition of the series...
$$
\sum _{i=k}^{n}{n\choose i}{x}^{i} \left( 1-x \right) ^{n-i}
={{n\choose k}\frac {{x}^{k}}{ \left( 1-x \right) ^{-n+k}}
\;{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}\left(1,-n+k;\,k+1;\,{\frac {x}{-1+x}}\right)}}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!